# PFQuery won't return value

Tags: ios, parsing, pfquery

So I am able to store data into my parse class, but I can't read out the values.

this is where i declare a relationship between my *Userinfo* class and my *User* class :

```
 PFObject *userObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserInfo"];
 [userObject setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"Username"];
```

i then set values in the UserInfo class and it stores correctly, but when i go to read the values out of the database i get no objects were read out.

```
PFQuery *load =[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserInfo"];
[load whereKey:@"Username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

[load findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    if(!error)
    {
        if (!error) {
            infoArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d obj.", infoArray.count); //this comes back as zero
            NSLog (@"idummy %@", infoArray);
        }
    }
}];
```

I feel like I'm close but missing one step, I also checked I do not have any code executing in my
 - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` 
besides my parse key and client id.

UPDATE:

So i have figured out the above issue:

NSString *ObjID=curr.objectId;

```
PFQuery *load =[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserInfo"];
[load whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:ObjID];
```

it works when i @"adf234" for the equalTo, but is there for me to search based on the NSString ObjID value? Because it doesn't work when i put ObjID like i have above.

Comment: What do you get in *error* object in `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`?

Comment: Where are you saving and how did you verify the save worked?

Comment: I am saving basic information about a user in the UserInfo class, like Name, Billing address, email , phone number. And i wanted to display this back on a tab page when the user is logged in. I verified that it is saving by logging on to my parse account and it shows the correct data that i registered for a user in the subclass UserInfo.

Comment: Are you running `[userObject saveInBackground ...` somewhere?

Comment: yes i am, i do that once the user clicks register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
PFQuery *load =[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserInfo"];
/*[load whereKey:@"Username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];*/ No need of this

[query includeKey:@"Username"];

[load findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
if(!error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d obj.",[[dict objectForKey:@"Username"] objectForKey:@"username"]);  

      /* I was also getting it null but if you try to nslog [PFUSer currentUser] you will get details but I tried for object key pair then got details so similarly you will get all other details of user by providing different keys.*/
    }
}
}];
```

Comment: This returned a username, i was wanting to get the information that is specific to the current user logged in.

Comment: It also wasn't the username of the current user logged in.

Comment: This provides u detail of current user I have created a demo but if you simply type, [[PFUSer current user] objectForKey:@"COLUMN_NAME_YOU_WANT_INFO_ABOUT"] ; Then u could get specific info about current user.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was setting my pointer before the new user saved once i fixed that your answer worked!! Thanks again!